# Kubernetes: How to use https communication between pods

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

I have two Pods and they are in the same kubernetes cluster
and Pod1 should communicate Pod2 over https.

I use the internal
Domainname: backend-srv.area.cluster.local
But howto generate and integrate a cert to Pod2(apache)?

Comment: We would be more able to help you if you said what you have tried that didn't work, followed by some error messages from your attempts.

Comment: I searched a solution for generating self-signed ssl with using kubernetes ca, but havent found.

Answer (score -1):

Your certificates should be generated and passed to apache by a [Kubernetes Secret Resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: apache-secret
data:
  cacerts: your_super_long_string_with_certificate
```

In your pod yaml configuration you're going to use that secret:

```
 volumes:      
   - name: certs
     secret:
       secretName: apache-secret
       items:
       - key: cacerts
         path: cacerts
```

I suggest you to use a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) to connect to your pods:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: apache
  name: apache
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: apache
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 30080
  selector:
    app: apache
  type: NodePort
```

Make the proper adjustments to my examples.

Comment: the internal domain is backend-srv.area.cluster.local within a Kubernetes Cluster. How can i create a certifcate for this internal (kubernetes created) domain? I think you explained me the general instruction for integrating an ssl certificate (that i know)...